# jQuery draggable div only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to generate a div from javascript and make it draggable. It is working however, the div is draggable only once. I would like it to be constantly draggable.

I understand that is is because the draggable attribute is within the function ad_annotation, but I do not know how else I could do it. Here is my code:

```
        <div id="controle_panel">
            <button id="add_annotation" class="btn btn-default" onclick="add_annotation()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> New annotation
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="video_commands">
            <div id="video-wrapper" class="video-wrapper">
                <video id="advertisment_video" margin-top="100px" class="video-js 
                       vjs-default-skin" preload="auto" data-setup="{}" controls />
                <source src=<?php echo '"' . $video["video_link"] . '"'; ?> type="video/mp4"></source>
            </div>
            <div id="annotation_confirmation" style="display: none;">
                <button id="confirm_annotation" class="btn btn-default" onclick="">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Confirm time and position
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    function add_annotation() {
        var v = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
        if (v.paused) {
            alert("Please start the video to place an annotation at the current time");
        } else {
            v.pause();
            var retVal = prompt("Enter the text of your anotation", "new anotation");
            if (retVal != "new annotation") {
                var e = $('<div style="background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); width: 25%;">' + retVal + '</div>');
                $('.video-wrapper').prepend(e);    
                e.attr('id', 'annotation'); 
                e.draggable({
                    containment: '#video-wrapper',
                    cursor: 'move',
                    snap: '#video-wrapper'
                });
                document.getElementById('annotation_confirmation').style.display = "inline";
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: `margin-top="100px"` Is it really work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend having the draggable container within the document and just show and update as you need it instead of creating a new one.

```
<div id="dragContainer" style="background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); width: 25%; display:none"></div>
```

Then in your javascript you can make it draggable on load

```
$(function() {
    $("#dragContainer").draggable({
                containment: '#video-wrapper',
                cursor: 'move',
                snap: '#video-wrapper'
             });
});
```

And modify your function:

```
function add_annotation(){
    var v = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]
    if (v.paused){
        alert("Please start the video to place an annotation at the current time");
    }else{
        v.pause();
        var retVal = prompt("Enter the text of your anotation", "new anotation");
        if (retVal != "new annotation"){

            $('#dragContainer').html(retVal).show();

            document.getElementById('annotation_confirmation').style.display ="inline";         
        }
    }
};
```

Then you just need to trigger a hide at some point when you want to get rid of the draggable container

Comment: Thanks for this however I have to be able to generate on. As you can see on my code I have a button that generate codes this allows the user to generate as many as he want this is part of the function of the page. After this I plan to save the  x and y of the div created and send it to a database.

Comment: Ok, perhaps you should append the created div to the body after it is created then

Comment: I think this is what i do on this line: $('.video-wrapper').prepend(e);